# Display all taxonomy, children and grandchildren with links

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a post type named Package, and have 4 taxonomy associated with it, treks, tours, adrenaline and expeditions.
 All of these taxonomies have chidren categories(eg. treks region 1, treks region 2.....), 
 and in those categories are multiple packages(content).
Now how can i display all taxonomies, their children and the title of all their packages,
with links(treks and it's children to taxonomy.php and packages to single-ntp_package.php)?
(i need to make a dropdown nav)
 i tried with wp_list_categories(), it just shows the children. can't even  pass all taxonomy types in array
i also tried get_object_taxonomies, it shows the taxonomy name like 'ntp_trek', the one i used to make it unique, not the one in 'labels',which is 'Treks'.
and i've tried all these functions with terms and objects, but can't get what i want.

Please help, i've been trying it from yesterday.
Thanks